# sqlalchemy filter table valued function

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

If I have a table valued function, so that the SQL looks like:

```
SELECT a, b FROM  tvf(c, d) where e = 3
```

Is it possible to express this in sqlalchemy without using raw strings?

```
select([column['name']]).select_from(func.func_name(*vars))
```

Gives me the above minus the were clause, but I can't find a way to put the where clause in anywhere.

```
func.funcname(*args).filter(column["colname"]=="val"]
```

gives a filterfunc instance, which I don't think is what I want

filtering the outer expression gives ("select object has no attribute filter")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want `.where()`

```
select([column['name']]).select_from(func.func_name(*vars)).where(column["colname"]=="val")
```

Relevant docs [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.where).